# Natural weapons with multi-turn touch attack spells

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, attack, touch-attacks, natural-weapon

Some spells use touch attacks to deliver their effects to the target. For many of these (like *[shocking grasp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shocking-grasp)*), the touch attack is discharged the first such time that happens. These clearly fall under this rule [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat):

> **Holding the Charge**: If you don't discharge the spell in the round when
>   you cast the spell, you can hold the charge indefinitely. You can
>   continue to make touch attacks round after round. If you touch
>   anything or anyone while holding a charge, even unintentionally, the
>   spell discharges. If you cast another spell, the touch spell
>   dissipates. You can touch one friend as a standard action or up to six
>   friends as a full-round action. Alternatively, you may make a normal
>   unarmed attack (or an attack with a natural weapon) while holding a
>   charge. In this case, you aren't considered armed and you provoke
>   attacks of opportunity as normal for the attack. If your unarmed
>   attack or natural weapon attack normally doesn't provoke attacks of
>   opportunity, neither does this attack. If the attack hits, you deal
>   normal damage for your unarmed attack or natural weapon and the spell
>   discharges. If the attack misses, you are still holding the charge

Others have specific language about how they interact with combat. *[Elemental touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/elemental-touch)* is one such spell:

> You gain a melee touch attack causing 1d6 points of damage of that
>   energy type, along with a special effect described below. You also
>   deal energy damage and the related special effect when you attack with
>   your hands using an unarmed strike, a single claw, or a single slam
>   attack. This bonus damage can never apply to multiple weapons.

So my question involves spells that grant touch attacks over a duration without a discharge, like *[disable construct](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/disable-construct)*:

> You can make a melee touch attack to send a pulse into the target, interfering with the magic that endows it with life.

(essentially, spells with range: touch that are some duration other than instantaneous without special language that explicitly outlines their behavior)

Can natural attacks be used to make "free" touch attacks with spells of this type, the same way as in the "Holding the Charge" clause (even if this isn't "holding" the charge, *per se*, since the spell is not instantaneous duration)? If so, can that happen only once per turn, or with every natural attack (if the creature has more than one)?

Comment: I want to make clear that I'm not antagonizing you by pointing this out—because some folks take this seriously—, but because "the spell affects creatures directly," the *disable construct* "result travels with the subjects for the spell's [duration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Duration)" instead of the spell's duration being the time allotted during which the caster can make touch attacks having that result. Hence the spell *disable construct* is discharged after one use. Is there a different example that you can use instead?

Comment: No antagony taken at all! I'm asking for clarifications precisely because I am fuzzy on what the rules say, I'm not going to get angry if I'm fuzzy in a way I didn't think I was fuzzy in. And this is why I like rpg.se better than the Paizo rules forums :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Only once per casting. *Disable construct* is a touch spell and uses exactly the same "Holding the charge" rules as other touch spells.

The duration stated in the spell refers to the number of assaults the *helpless* effect lasts. You do only perform one touch attack after casting the spell. Then, either the attack is successful and the spell discharges on the touched target or the attack fails and you hold the charge normally.

Comment: Yes: "You can make **a** melee touch attack"

Comment: I'm not sure just correcting question's misunderstanding of the example spell answers the question unless there really are *no* spells that actually meet the asker's criteria. (Also, do you mean *assaults* in that sentence or *rounds*?)

Comment: Accepting as written--if someone can find an example that doesn't have a "target" of "creature touched", then they can ask me to edit in that example.

Answer (score 1):

[Chill touch](http://archivesofnethys.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Chill%20Touch) is a spell that allows several uses instead of just holding one charge, so that is a spell that fits your topic, but from your question my answer might be off-topic.
Chill touch, once cast, can be delivered 1/CL. For example if you are 10th level you cast it once and then you can use it to deliver the effect up to 10 times. And this can be through touches or natural attacks.

If you just wanted to know if you had it right with disable construct forget my answer, the comment by Hey I Can Chan and the answer by Balcertar cleared that up already.

Comment: Chill touch is actually specified more completely than I was looking to answer--my misunderstanding was the root of the question, because I thought I'd found a spell that gave a touch attack as a "buff" without specifying its terms of use (the way elemental touch does), but what I'd actually found was a range touch spell whose *effect* had a non-instantaneous duration.

Answer (score 1):

The spell [calcific touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/calcific-touch/) matches the situation you described. I'm no authority, but I believe it has been ruled that calcific touch can be delivered via natural attacks. Generalized, I guess that means you should be able to deliver touch spells via natural attacks; though the free touch attack you get on the round you cast the spell is just that; a single touch attempt, not a natural attack attempt.

This [thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ks?How-does-calcific-touch-work-How-do-the) is a discussion of calcific touch and how it works in general, including with natural attacks. The author of the spell got involved, so his comments can be taken as RAI for that spell.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour), it's a useful introduction to the site. Can you provide a source for the ruling?